# PHP while() loop Duplicating MySQL Rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a nested `while()` inside of another that both query different tables and pull information from them.

I then do a MySQL query where I insert all the data into a different database.

```
$grad5app = mysqli_query($grad5app_connect, "SELECT * FROM applicant_academic");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($grad5app)) {
    $applicationId = $row[0];
    $startYear = $row[10];
    $startSemester = $row[9];
    $hasBeenSubmitted = $row[2];
    $submittedDate = $row[8];
    $essayOldFileName = $row[15];
    $resumeOldFileName = $row[16];

    if ($startYear == "") {
        $startYear = 'NULL';
    }
    if ($startSemester == "") {
        $startSemester = 'NULL';
    }

    $grad5app1 = mysqli_query($grad5app_connect, "SELECT * FROM applicants");
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($grad5app1)) {
        $createdDate = $row1[116];
        $lastModified = $row1[117];
        $desiredHousing = $row1[58];
        $transactionId = $row1[152];
        $hasBeenPushed = $row1[126];
        $pushedDate = $row1[119];
        $hashReference = $row1[8];
        $waiveReferenceViewingRights = $row1[145];
        $hasUmaineCorrespondent = $row1[144];
        $umaineCorrespondentDetails = $row1[81];
        $hasAcceptedTermsOfAgreement = $row1[150];
    }

    mysqli_query($gradschool_application_2_connect, "INSERT INTO Application ".
        "(applicationId, applicantId, applicationTypeId, createdDate, lastModified, startYear, startSemester, desiredHousing, ".
        "hasUmaineCorrespondent, umaineCorrespondentDetails, hasAcceptedTermsOfAgreement, transactionId, hasBeenSubmitted, ".
        "submittedDate, hasBeenPushed, pushedDate, hashReference, waiveReferenceViewingRights, essayOldFileName, resumeOldFileName) ".
        "VALUES ('".$applicationId."', '".$applicationId."', 1, '".$createdDate."', '".$lastModified."', ".$startYear.", ".
        "'".$startSemester."', '".$desiredHousing."', '".$hasUmaineCorrespondent."', '".$umaineCorrespondentDetails."', '".$hasAcceptedTermsOfAgreement."', ".
        "'".$transactionId."', '".$hasBeenSubmitted."', '".$submittedDate."', '".$hasBeenPushed."', '".$pushedDate."', '".$hashReference."', ".
        "'".$waiveReferenceViewingRights."', '".$essayOldFileName."', '".$resumeOldFileName."')");

    echo "INSERTED";
       echo"<br>".$lastModified."<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
INSERTED
2013-11-14 12:10:56
INSERTED
2013-11-14 12:10:56
INSERTED
2013-11-14 12:10:56
INSERTED
2013-11-14 12:10:56
INSERTED
2013-11-14 12:10:56
INSERTED
2013-11-14 12:10:56
INSERTED
2013-11-14 12:10:56
INSERTED
2013-11-14 12:10:56
INSERTED
2013-11-14 12:10:56
INSERTED
2013-11-14 12:10:56
INSERTED
2013-11-14 12:10:56
INSERTED
2013-11-14 12:10:56
INSERTED
2013-11-14 12:10:56
INSERTED
2013-11-14 12:10:56
```

The `applicants` table has unique `$lastModified` dates so there should not be duplicates. Clearly my while loop structure is messed up. Can anybody help me?

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)?

When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: There is no user input. This script is only run once to move data from an old database to a new one. It does not need to be secure.

Answer (score 0):

Why should it ever change?

```
While (...) {
   while (...) {
        $lastModified = $row1[117];
   }
   insert into ...
}
```

Since you're setting `$lastModified` inside that inner while() loop, and then not using it until AFTER the loop completes, it will ALWAYS have the LAST value fetched inside the loop. The query never changes, so you always get the same records, which means you also always get the same final value.

Perhaps your structure should be more like:

```
while(...) {
   while(...) {
       $lastModified = ...
       insert into ...
   }
}
```

instead.

Comment: I tried that too. Every row contains `2010-12-19 01:27:23` as the lastModified column which is the first row in the fetched table.

Comment: the echo should be in the inner loop too

Comment: It is. The echo isn't what matters, it's the fact that I'm getting duplicated data.

Comment: well, how many records are there in the `applicant` table? Remember that your loop fetching the rows from that table doesn't actually **DO** anything except continually overwrite all of those variables. If you have (say) 200 records in the table, then you'll only ever be using record #200's data.

Comment: The `applicants` table has 14 rows.

Comment: so your code is getting all 14, fetching+throwing away 1-13, then using record #14 for your insert query.

Comment: +1. Marc B has succinctly explained why we would fully expect that `$last_modified` would always be the same. The only time it's different is when the code is spinning through the first 13 rows from the query. That variable `$last_modified` is only referenced AFTER the 14th (last) row returned by the query has been fetched.